# TCP handshake not happening between windows client and linux server

Tags: java, linux, windows, tcp, onvif

I'm really scratching my head around this one.

I'm running a java server against a few test cases through a test tool and I'm getting a java socket timed out exception. The test tool runs on windows, while my server is deployed on a Raspbian. The test tool is black box so I do not know its implementation.

From what I gathered, the test case creates a client sending an http address to my server, say http://192.168.1.100:8080, in which my server is to make a connection and send data back to it. The port number is not static.

I verified that the port is opened by the system each test. I then placed Wireshark on the test tool's machine and found that the Syn packet made it to the machine, but Syn/Ack was never sent out.
I'm using java httpURLConnection, but I've also tried to make a java socket but both resulted in the same and throwing a socket timed out.

This problem does not come up if I run the server locally with with the test tool. What make this stranger is that it also happens to another code base, which is supposed to pass the test.

I don't know why it would not connect to the port.

More information: I'm working on an Onvif device controller. Onvif essentially provides a common interface between video streaming device and client applications. The server needs to conform to Onvif specs and passes the Onvif device test tool.

The problem above happens with test cases related to base event handlings, which follows [WS-BaseNotification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/wsn-ws_base_notification-1.3-spec-os.pdf) specs.The serer is given an endpoint so it can use to notify the client. However, given that that I'm getting a socket timed out, I don't think it is a schema parsing problem. The server throw an exception before any data was written to the output stream. The same problem happens with another code base which is supposed to be pass the test tool but the test tool also report that the notification was not delivered.

Comment: Whenever you have such problems of connectivity from A to B then try to verify with a **neutral tool**. In the old days people would use **telnet client** to do a crude connectivity test from A to B. But your client is on Windows so you have a much better alternative, namely the [Test-NetConnection command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection) in PowerShell. Please verify using that tool, e.g. `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.1.100 -Port 80 -InformationLevel "Detailed"`, and post result.

Comment: If you can see an outgoing SYN but not an incoming SYN+ACK then there are the following possibilities: the SYN never reaches the server machine (firewall or similar in between), the SYN gets blocked by the machine (firewall on the machine), the SYN+ACK never reaches the client (unlikely, at least compared to the other options). To dig further you need to run a packet capture (like tcpdump) on the target machine.

Comment: @peterh Thanks for the help guys. I ran the test at home and it seems turning off the private firewall fixed it. At work I we have a domain firewall and I do not have control over it, so it seems that is the problem. I assume that the domain firewall would still be active even if the machine is disconnected form the network? I don't know much about IT stuff so when we tested our server by connecting directly with the test tool machine, having both turned disconnected from the network, and it was still blocking we assumed that firewall was not the issue.